# Is there a way to set a Treelist field in the core database to point to a folder in the master database?

Tags: sitecore-client

I am creating a Template in core database for a Custom User Profile. I have a Treelist field and I would like to point to a folder in master database. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
datasource=/sitecore/content/home&databasename=master
```

Please find more informations here: http://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality

Comment: mark the answer as correct answer

Comment: Will do. When a hit the button it says that I have to wait 10 minutes.